# Transaction Scope With API calls

Tags: c#, asp.net, transactionscope

I am working on a process that is distributed and dependent on some internal db operations as well as some third-party APIs. I want to leverage the transaction scope capabilities to roll back if at any point an error occurs.

Here is how my flow works.

User Registration Process

1. Fills our basic information that is being inserted into my database using Dapper ORM.
2. Half of the filled information is passed to third-party APIs.
3. If API call succeeds the user is registered into our payment system via payment gateways API.

Now here is the case that I am worried about. Let's say #1 & #2 completed successfully and while performing #3 it failed due to any reason. Will transaction scope revert the #1 and #2 in that case? I am sure about the #1 but will it be handled for #2 as well? If not what is the alternate solution that I can implement in this scenario.

Comment: Well what sort of API call are you talking about?  A library call or network call?  WCF supports transactions with certain transports.   REST won't

Comment: @MickyD I want to make REST API calls to Stripe payment gateway as #3. I just want the process to be failproof that if for any reason Stripe API returns error #1 and #2 should be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

you Cannot. Only thing you can achieve is if API call fails you can rollback your transaction

No way you will have control over what happened at the API.

But this can be done with mutual understanding with some Errorcode say if i send back "Error" which means i rolled back and you  also rollback

Comment: And if it the values where committed in the database for the called method over the REST call, but the connection back had an error? You would changed the database for the called method and rollback the caller.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is something that you generally should try to avoid, that is, making REST API calls part of transactions. But, if you still need to do this for whaterver reason, you need to implement the transaction coordinator yourself.

In your case, use a transactionScope around the dapper insert and call the API. If something goes wrong, send a new request to a different method in the API to rollback what ever you did as part of the transaction.

```
try {
        using (var ts = new TransactionScope())
        {
          // insert data using dapper
          // Do your API Call
          ts.Complete()
        }
   }
  catch(Exception)
  {
     // Rollback your API call. 
  }
```

Comment: Got your point and that's what I was wondering whether or not API calls are reverted if the transaction fails. I think I will have to manually handle this situation.